# Need help in splitting the date value in a column to a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I've the below column in one of my table.

```
DB_Attribute
Attributes: ServerId=300000049436:DBCOP01; CountryCode=HK; Environment=LIVE; 
ServerName=BCOINST@HK000HSP2717; ServerStatus=ACTIVE; ViewPointName=DBA HTSA HASE; 
LifecycleStatus=Active; assetGroup=bcoinst; BusinessCriticality=TIER 2; GSDServiceCount=1; 
HSBCLocation=HK HHQ; DBCount=1; GSDServiceName=HASE-BCO; LastChange=2017/10/29  20:00:01; DBTimeStamp=2017/10/29

Attributes: ViewPointName=DBA HTSA - DB2; BusinessCriticality=TIER 2; 
ServerId=300000027610:VNPRD1HF; HSBCLocation=HK TKO; Environment=LIVE; LifecycleStatus=Active; 
assetGroup=ap4vnpu1; DBCount=1; GSDServiceCount=2; DBTimeStamp=2017/10/29; 
GSDServiceName=VNM AAPS4; ServerStatus=ACTIVE; LastChange=2017/10/29  20:00:01; ServerName=AP4VNPU1@HKP02LP2311; CountryCode=HK

Attributes: ServerId=300000028881:KWTAS; CountryCode=HK; DBTimeStamp=2017/10/29; 
LastChange=2017/10/29  20:00:01; LifecycleStatus=Active; DBCount=1; HSBCLocation=HK TKO; 
ViewPointName=DBA HTSA - DB2; Environment=LIVE; BusinessCriticality=TIER 2; GSDServiceName=GWIS KWT; 
ServerStatus=ACTIVE; ServerName=DB2IKWTA@HKPA2LS0024; GSDServiceCount=1

Attributes: DBTimeStamp=2017/07/12; LifecycleStatus=Active; DBCount=3; 
Environment=LIVE; LastChange=2017/07/13  20:00:02; ServerId=300000027589:VNVNP3JL; 
BusinessCriticality=TIER 1; GSDServiceCount=0; ServerStatus=ACTIVE; CountryCode=HK; HSBCLocation=HK TKO; 
GSDServiceName=VNM HFE2; ViewPointName=DBA HTSA - DB2; ServerName=HFEVNPU2@HKP02LP0620

Attributes: ServerStatus=ACTIVE; Environment=LIVE; GSDServiceName=JPM HFE2; 
LastChange=2017/10/29  20:00:01; ServerId=300000027592:JPJPP3HF; LifecycleStatus=Active; 
ServerName=HFEJPPU1@HKP02LP0720; BusinessCriticality=TIER 2; GSDServiceCount=1; HSBCLocation=HK TKO; 
CountryCode=HK; DBCount=3; ViewPointName=DBA HTSA - DB2; DBTimeStamp=2017/10/29
```

From the above **DB_Attribute** column you can see there is a value called **DBTimeStamp**, now my requirement is I'm looking for a query to put the **DBTimeStamp** into a new column.

Regards,

Vikas

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Is that sample table data? What is the expected result?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I would like to see the date in DBTimeStamp in another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle try use function REGEXP_SUBSTR to get **DBTimeStamp** by regular expression

Example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Example text in database column', '(\S*)(\s)')
FROM dual;
```

Result is 'Example '

Oracle doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm

Comment: Not able to write a query, can you help me in constructing a query please?

Comment: Ok, I write regular expression to cut your date: **(?<=DBTimeStamp=)[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}**

Try this query:

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (DB_Attribute , '(?<=DBTimeStamp=)[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}')
FROM your_table;`

Repleace table name to your table.

Comment: Thanks for that I tried your query and changed it to my table name, but it is giving me the `NULL` values.

Comment: Please paste your query - i try test in my database on data from your question. You use oracle database right?

Comment: yes I'm using Oracle and here is my query `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (DB_Attribute , '(?<=DBTimeStamp=)[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}')  as Dates FROM your_table` and I tired this query `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (DB_Attribute , 'DBTimeStamp=[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}') as Dates FROM your_table` but it is giving me output like **DBTimeStamp=2017/10/29** and **DBTimeStamp=2017/07/12**

Comment: I see in oracle not work regexp (?<=).

Try this (is workaround):

`select REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR (DB_Attribute, 'DBTimeStamp=[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}'), 'DBTimeStamp=', '')
from your_table ;`